# Why function with name "clear" doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, naming

I wrote a small HTML file. I added few buttons with onclick attributes and wrote my functions inside a "script" tag. All of them are working perfect but the function with name "clear" doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="copy();" />
  <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear();" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  function copy() {
    console.log("copy");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      document.getElementById("result_box").value
    );
  }

  function clear() {
    console.log("clear");
  }
```

When I click on both of this buttons browser console shows me only one message: "copy". No errors.

If I change the name of this function it starts working. I don't understand why is it happening. I thought the word "clear" is reserved word of JavaScript but I couldn't find this word in the list of keywords in documentation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is that `clear()` inside a button calls document.clear instead of your clear.